# Ввести целые числа n и i и вывести целое число, у которого i бит сброшен в 0, а все остальные биты совпадают с битами

Tags: c#

Задание: Ввести целые числа n и i и вывести целое число, у которого i-й бит
сброшен в 0, а все остальные биты совпадают с битами числа n на тех же
позициях. Например, если введены 11 и 1, ответом будет 9.

Нужна помощь. Не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы менялся 1-ый бит, а не 0-ой. При вводе n = 11 получается 10, а должно 9. Когда меняю i, например на 2, то получается 8.

```
       Console.WriteLine("Введите n: ");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Введите i: ");
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine($"Число {n} в двоичном виде = {Convert.ToString(n, 2)}");

        n >>= i;
        n <<= i;
        string number = Convert.ToString(n, 2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Получилось число {number}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Число {number} в десятичном виде = {Convert.ToInt32(number, 2)}");
```

Comment: <br>
Не силён в с#, да и пишу с телефона, но у Вас ошибка в двоичных вычислениях. Посмотрите по ссылке, там как раз написано как сбросить в ноль нужный бит.<br>
https://hubstub.ru/programming/64-kak-ustanovit-sbrosit-proverit-nuzhnyy-bit-ili-bitovyye-operatsii.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

по сути, вам нужно:

1. Взять единичку, двоичный вид `00000001`
2. Сдвинуть её на нужную вам позицию, например `00001000` (делается так `1 << i`)
3. Инвертировать полученную маску, то есть `11110111` `~(1 << i)`
4. Использовать логическое умножение, чтобы выставить нужный бит в 0 по маске `n= n & ~(1 << i);`